# Unable to process data using sscanf

Tags: c

I need to traverse a string data and store the values in it in separate feilds to perform operations on this data later. I am trying to use sscanf to acheive this but while using sscanf I am facing issues in getting the desired results. Data is not gettimng separated as required. I think it might be a syntax issue as I am new to C language.

I already tried doing the same by providing arguments and formats to seperate the text but it did not work.

```
XYZ123 CONFIRMED MT 2019-04-30T13:30:00+02:00
```

In the above string I need to separate XYZ123, second I need CONFIRMED, third MT and the rest of the data in 4th field.

```
sscanf(pMMFk81->or4wnew,"%10[^ ]%c%10[^ ]%c%10[^ ]%c%100[^\0]", 
    szBusField1, space, szBusField2, space1, szBusField3, space2);
```

Peice of code

```
void AddBsiAttributeSection(PARSED_XML * pXML,
    int ixLevel1,
    OR4WR81 * pMMFk81) {
    int ixLevel2 = 0;
    int ixLevel3 = 0;
    int ixLevel4 = 0;
    char space[10] = "";
    char space1[10] = "";
    char space2[10] = "";
    char szBusField1[10] = "";
    char szBusField2[10] = "";
    char szBusField3[10] = "";
    char szBusField4[10] = "";
    char szData[80 + 1] = "";

    // ----------------------
    // Set up
    //      <xsd:Attribute>
    //          <xsd:Name>BusID</xsd:Name>
    //          <xsd:CurrentValue>
    //              <xsd:STRING>XYZ1234</xsd:STRING>
    //          </xsd:CurrentValue>
    //          <xsd:Attribute>
    // ----------------------

    sscanf(pMMFk81 - > or4wnew, "%10[^ ] %10[^ ] %10[^ ] %100[^\0]", szBusField1, szBusField2, szBusField3, szBusField4);

    ixLevel2 = XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel1, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_Attribute, "");
    XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel2, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_Name, FIRXML_AFEN_BUSID);
    ixLevel3 = XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel2, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_CurrentValue, "");
    //  sprintf (szData,"%6.6s",pASTk80->or4blcc);
    XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel3, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_STRING, szBusField1);

    // ----------------------
    // Set up
    //  <xsd:Attribute>
    //      <xsd:Name>Qualifier</xsd:Name>
    //      <xsd:CurrentValue>
    //          <xsd:STRING>ARRIVED_DROPOFF</xsd:STRING>
    //      </xsd:CurrentValue>
    //  </xsd:Attribute>
    // ----------------------

    ixLevel3 = XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel2, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_Attribute, "");
    XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel3, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_Name, FIRXML_AFEN_QUALIFIER);
    ixLevel4 = XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel3, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_CurrentValue, "");
    //  sprintf (szData,"%3.3s",pStnArr);           // Arrival station
    XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel4, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_STRING, szBusField2);

    // ----------------------
    // Set up
    //  <xsd:Attribute>
    //      <xsd:Name>Source</xsd:Name>
    //      <xsd:CurrentValue>
    //          <xsd:STRING>MT</xsd:STRING>
    //      </xsd:CurrentValue>
    //  </xsd:Attribute>
    // ----------------------

    ixLevel3 = XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel2, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_Attribute, "");
    XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel3, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_Name, FIRXML_AFEN_SOURCE);
    ixLevel4 = XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel3, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_CurrentValue, "");
    XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel4, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_STRING, szBusField3);

    // ----------------------
    //  <xsd:Attribute>
    //      <xsd:Name>BusTime</xsd:Name>
    //      <xsd:CurrentValue>
    //          <xsd:DATETIME>2019-04-30T13:32:00+01:00</xsd:DATETIME>
    //      </xsd:CurrentValue>
    //  </xsd:Attribute>
    // ----------------------

    ixLevel3 = XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel2, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_Attribute, "");
    XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel3, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_Name, FIRXML_AFEN_BUSTIME);
    ixLevel4 = XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel3, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_CurrentValue, "");
    XML_AddElement(pXML, ixLevel4, FIRXML_NS_XSD, FIRXML_AFEN_STRING, szBusField4);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Note: similar to [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294617/how-to-extract-data-from-sscanf).

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it did not work. I am getting XYZ123 in field1, 02:00 in field 2, T13:30:00+02:00 in field 3 and 2019-04-30T13:30:00+02:00 in field 4 with the above changes

Comment: It should be `&space` and `&space1` but it's easier to get the format string to do that by adding spaces there: `"%10[^ ] %10[^ ] %10[^ ] %100[^\0]"` or as @xing wrote.

Comment: If i use the %10[^ ] %10[^ ] %10[^ ] %100[^\0] format I am able to get correct value for XYZ123, CONFIRMED and MT. But I am not getting any data in timestamp field.

Comment: When your recently posted the similar question you were asked to post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Where is it? What that means is a short program that demonstrates the fault that can be copy/pasted and compiled by commenters.

Comment: @xing the source string is correct. In debugging I can see hex data is E7E8E9F1F2F340C3D6D5C6C9D9D4C5C440D4E340F2F0F1F960F0F460F3F0E3F1F37AF3F07AF0F04EF0F27AF0F000

Comment: Have you tried what was suggested in the first comment (from xing)?

Comment: Yes I tried using sscanf ( pMMFk81->or4wnew, "%10s%10s%10s%100s", szBusField1, szBusField2, szBusField3, timestamp); but I am getting XYZ123 in field1, 02:00 in field 2, T13:30:00+02:00 in field 3 and 2019-04-30T13:30:00+02:00 in field 4 with the above changes –

Comment: You have told `sscanf` that `char szBusField4[10]` has room for `100` bytes. The buffer overflow is causing havoc.

Comment: Even if I try 100 bytes it doesn't work.

Comment: You have also told sscanf that the other three buffers have room for 10 bytes but they only have room for 9 (plus terminator). That should not matter with the example data you show because `CONFIRMED` is 9 characters but perhaps you have other data which is longer.

Comment: But there must be some way to process variable length data also

Comment: The code you posted does not show the result of the `sccanf`. You have not yet understood what the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is. It should be a complete program, with its `#include` files and a `main()` and the 6 or so lines of code necessary to replicate the problem. If nothing else, you can assure yourself that you are using `sscanf` correctly, and that the problems are somewhere else in the code.